# javascript Button Doing Nothing onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, spinner, form-submit

First of all, I am not very good at javascript. Well what I am trying to do is create a sort of wheel spinning program where, on a button click, you will either get extra spins, nothing, or it will send me an email with a secret code and I will reply in the email how much they will win. Hopefully you understand what I mean and know why its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<title>Spin the Wheel!</title>
</head>
<body>
<button name="generate" type="button" onClick="gennum()">Spin!</button>

<script>
function gennum() {
var result=Math.floor(Math.random()*101)
check()
}

function check()  {
if (result > 0 && result < 11) {
alert("You win 1 free spin! Spin again!")
}
else if (result > 10 && result < 16) {
alert("You win 2 free spins! Spin again twice!")
}
else if (result > 15 && result < 26) {
alert("Sorry, you won nothing. Please try again tommorow.")
}
else if (result > 25 && result < 36) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('7L6XPaY8').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 35 && result < 45) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('NmE6B5uF').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 44 && result < 52) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('ZpLb9TRC').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 51 && result < 59) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('JQa6fGHH').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 58 && result < 64) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('rKjPGXak').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 63 && result < 69) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('5QQyCJaD').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 68 && result < 71) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('474zbnkE').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 70 && result < 74) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('QUjY2NSN').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 73 && result < 76) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('FNVYSHu5').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
else if (result > 75 && result < 100) {
alert("Sorry, you won nothing. Please try again tommorow.")
}
else if (result = 100) {
    var link = "mailto:name@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("Spinner")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('uZ63V4me').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That is all of the code. If you know why it is not working, reply please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `result` to the function otherwise it's out of scope:

```
function gennum() {
  var result=Math.floor(Math.random()*101)
  check(result)
}

function check(result)  {
  ...
}
```

In your case `result` is defined inside `gennum` and `check` has no access to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is not declared as a `global` variable, so it is empty when it reaches `check()`.

Pass it as a `parameter` on `check()`

```
function gennum() {
 var result=Math.floor(Math.random()*101)
 check(result);
}

function check(param)  {
 // and so on and so forth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare `result` variable outside of your function to publically access it through all methods

```
var result;
function gennum() {
  result=Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
  check();
}
function check()  {
//do something here ...
}
```

or
you should to declare a parameter for `check` function and pass value to it.

```
function gennum() {
  var result=Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
  check(result);
}
function check(result)  {
//do something here ...
}
```